# Pandas: if the word "Action" precedes the word "Dialouge", fill the timeline of Action same as Dialouge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make the value of Action timeline = Dialogue timeline, only if Action comes before dialogue:

```
x = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['Type'][i] == "Action" < df['Type'][i] == "Dialouge":
        x.append(df['Timeline'])[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a boolean mask on the conditions, then set the rows of column `Timeline` fulfilling the conditions to the corresponding values of next rows by [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), as follows:

(Note the spelling/mispelling if the word `Dialouge` (rather than `Dialogue`) in the sample data)

```
mask = (df['Timeline'].isna() | (df['Timeline'] == '')) & (df['Type'] == "Action") & (df['Type'].shift(-1) == "Dialouge")

df.loc[mask, 'Timeline'] = df['Timeline'].shift(-1)
```

**Data Input:**

```
       Type  Timeline
0    Action       NaN
1  Dialouge  00:05:54
2    Action       NaN
3  Dialouge  00:06:06
4    Action       NaN
5  Dialouge       NaN
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

       Type  Timeline
0    Action  00:05:54
1  Dialouge  00:05:54
2    Action  00:06:06
3  Dialouge  00:06:06
4    Action       NaN
5  Dialouge       NaN
```